# Multiple commands in declareGraphicsRule - how to do it?

Tags: pdftex, epstopdf

Although I'm not sure the graphicsRule below will do what I want, the main point is that it is not even generating the second eps file (epstool_tmp.eps) at all. What is going wrong?

Here's an example with [tiger.eps](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/lgc2/pstricks/tiger.eps):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{%
  epstool --copy --bbox #1 --output epstool_tmp.eps;
  epstopdf epstool_tmp.eps \OutputFile
}


\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Here is an image ... or not!}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight,width=0.53\textwidth]
{tiger.eps}
\end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `epstopdf` is wrong, the output file is given with option `--outfile`:

```
epstopdf epstool_tmp./eps --outfile \OutputFile
```

Also you need option `-shell-escape` for `pdflatex`, because several commands in one command line are not allowed with restricted shell escape. `epstool` is not in the default list of commands, which is allowed for restricted shell escape,
see variable `shell_escape_commands` in `texmf.cnf`.