# How to correctly clip with viewports with includegraphics and beamer columns?

Tags: beamer, graphics, bounding-box

I will happily accept any alternative to beamer's columns and `\includegraphics` that produces the intended result in a beamer slide.

I'm trying to take the [attached eps](https://app.box.com/s/5exqcr4leq9rd2bsetsj) file and reorganize it so that it fits in to a beamer slide by using viewports and clip to have effectively 3 separately cropped images. PNG version:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,red,notes]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=13 730 671 1146, clip=true]
{SmatExample}
\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=13 439 722 722, clip=true]
{SmatExample}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=13 13 722 435, clip=true]
{SmatExample}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, it almost works, but the cropping slightly cuts off the letters, and also cuts in to the bottom of Figure B, putting the bottom of Figure B in to the top of Figure C (it is hard to tell in this low resolution version, but there should be no lines above "S Matrix" in Figure C):
[image]

When I check the viewport coordinates in gsview, they look correct, both at the original high resolution (100ppi) and the attached 30ppi image.

---

Note: I have recently asked two questions in an attempt to get at this one, which has helped in some ways, but I feel I am no closer to the answer (thanks for the help so far!):

[Multiple commands in declareGraphicsRule - how to do it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180518/multiple-commands-in-declaregraphicsrule-how-to-do-it)

[auto-correct bounding box for eps files that simply wrap a bitmap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180517/auto-correct-bounding-box-for-eps-files-that-simply-wrap-a-bitmap)

Additionally, playing with `resolution=xxx` did not seem to have an effect for `\includegraphcis`. See

[Image from \includegraphics showing in wrong image size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/image-from-includegraphics-showing-in-wrong-image-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`epstopdf` takes the bounding box of `SmatExample.eps`:

```
%%BoundingBox: 14 14 723 1147
```

to create the PDF file. The image is moved to (0,0),
and a new media size is calculated:

```
/MediaBox [0 0 709 1133]
```

The coordinates of `gv`/`gsview`/... are based on the EPS version. For the PDF version and `viewport`, the coordinates needs to be corrected by subtracting the old origin values of the bounding box. Actually the following example subtracts 13 in both cases:

```
\documentclass[compress,red,notes]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 717 658 1133, clip]{SmatExample}
\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 426 709 709, clip]{SmatExample}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 0 709 422, clip]{SmatExample}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\fbox` is helpful for a visual control of the viewports:

```
\documentclass[compress,red,notes]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}

\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 717 658 1133, clip]{SmatExa
\\
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 426 709 709, clip]{SmatExam
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, viewport=0 0 709 422, clip]{SmatExampl
\end{column}
\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with frames]

Comment: To make one's images portable then, it seems the best solution is to adjust all bounding boxes to have the lower left corner at (0, 0)?

Comment: @bbarker: For portability with all kind of drivers: yes.